# How to force a service's bitness

Tags: c#, windows-services, 32bit-64bit

I have several  C# Windows service. One insists on running as a 64 bit process.

This wouldn't be a problem except that I migrated all shared configuration, to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

As a result the service fails to read the config, and for the moment I am having to duplicate the shared configuration (which defeats the point of moving it to machine.config)

I have changed the build configuration from x64 to x86, and re-installed but the service still runs in 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute Corflags /+32Bit [Service.Exe] (part of the .Net SDK) which will notify the OS that this assembly must be loaded in 32 bit mode.

Comment: Interesting, and the build configuration setting doesn't force the corflags header? I assume this needs to be run manually (or as a post build step) every time the service assembly is recompiled, prior to it being installed?

Comment: It's possible that your overall build config is x86 but that this set your MSI or C to be 32bit, but left your .Net assemblies as AnyCPU?

Comment: If you set the build config for the service executable to 32bit then this should be equivalent to setting corflags +32.  However I'm trying to help rule out that running as 64bit is your actual issue.

Comment: actually its the project's build config, not the solution configuration that I changed to x86. Either way your solution seems to be a workaround.  I'll mark it as the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: check that its fixed the problem first before marking the answer.  Corflags is extremely useful for retrospectively forcing an AnyCPU DLL that you don't have source code for to load in 32Bit for apps not designed to work properly in 64 bit.